# PHP DateTime format Year bug

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

this is the first time i encountered this bug, i usually use the same syntax to format dates. but now, i don't know what happened to `DateTime` format.

I've tried searching some resources, including Carbon and php DateTime formatting. but no luck.

PS: i am using laravel and it automatically extends timestamps into `Carbon` instance.

[image]

Comment: What is the data?  You can dump **$user->created_at**

Comment: i've figured it out. lol
year was not in a correct format

thanks tho

Answer (score -3):

i've figured it out. lol year was not in a correct format